# Find dy/dx, given only y...

Tags: calculus, functions, chain-rule

Use the chain rule to find $dy/dx$ for
$y= [3x^2-13]^3$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have function $\frac{d}{dx}[f(g(x))] = f'(g(x))g'(x)$, not sure how to create a composition of functions from the given expression.

Comment: I 'll help you help yourself. Write down the chain rule in your question, and try to understand where you can apply it. Can you create a composition of functions, from the given expression?

Comment: "*not sure how to create a composition of functions*..." Brackets are usually a good way to organize your thoughts... do you see any brackets or parenthesis in the original?   $y=[\dots]^3$ should look like something

Comment: Should g(x)=3x^2 - 13?

Comment: @Czar That's a great start. Now, can you figure out $f$?

Comment: Would this be x^3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Your function is given by $y(x) = f(g(x))$ with
$$f(x) = x^3, \quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad g(x) = 3x^2-13.$$
Now apply the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the values. I came to conclude those values, thus plugging into f'(g(x))g'(x) would render 18x(3x^2-13)^2

Comment: You are completely correct.